# MS Office 2013 compatibility with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, ms-office

On a standalone machine, SharePoint 2016 is installed. On that very machine can MS Office 2013 be installed?

Will it hamper any SharePoint 2016 functionalities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue to install Office 2013 64x on SharePoint 2016 machine